# RegEx to split query string with native JS

Tags: javascript, regex

Where window.location.search is

```
?foo=myFoo&fooAndBar=myFoo%26Bar;bar=myBar
```

What regular expression would correctly split the string at its query separators? Note that ampersand (`&`) and semicolon (`;`) are both [valid separators](http://www.w3.org/TR/1999/REC-html401-19991224/appendix/notes.html#h-B.2.2).

Sample use:

```
// slice() is used just to trim the leading "?"
window.location.search.slice(1).split(/ _WORKING_REGEX_ /);

>>> [object Array]:

    [0] => "foo=myFoo",
    [1] => "fooAndBar=myFoo&Bar",
    [2] => "bar=myBar"
```

I've found the correct match for ampersands, but not semicolons:

```
/&(?!\w+;)/
```

**EDIT:** T.J. Crowder pointed out that my error was in the original URL encoding of using `&amp;` as an escaped ampersand where it would be correctly encoded instead as `%26`. Given that, the correct RegEx is much easier to match

```
window.location.search.slice(1).split(/[&;]/)
```

Here is the original test URL I posted before the correction for reference:

```
?foo=myFoo&fooAndBar=myFoo&amp;Bar;bar=myBar
```

Comment: Doesn't look like any of those solutions cover semicolons as asked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Note that ampersand (&) and semicolon (;) are both valid separators.

So, um:

```
var pairs = queryString.split(/[;&]/);
```

?

Or, to deal with the potential `?` at the beginning:

```
var pairs = queryString.replace(/^\??/, '').split(/[;&]/);
```

Comment: @NathanWitt: `&amp;` does not represent an ampersand in a query string. Only in HTML. HTML != query string, completely distinct and unrelated notations.

Comment: @TJ it's not intended to, which is why your match creates a false-positive.

Comment: ["foo=myFoo","fooAndBar=myFoo","amp","Bar","bar=myBar"]

Comment: @NathanWitt: No. A query string containing the sequence `&amp;` **correctly** decodes to having an `amp` entry. That's my point. `&amp;` is *not special* in query strings. It's an ampersand (which is a separator), followed by `amp`, followed by a semicolon (which is kind of a separator, but not really). The notation `&mumble;` is HTML-specific and not used in query strings, as I said. (It's SGML-derived, I believe; SGML and HTML have nothing to do with query strings.) The correct way to put a **literal** ampersand in a query string is `%26`.

Comment: Where you're running into trouble is understanding when things are parsed. In the **HTML** markup `<a href="http://example.com?x=1&amp;y=1">...</a>`, the query string is **not** `?x=1&amp;y=1`, it's `x=1&y=1`. The `&amp;` relates to how we *write* the HTML `href` attribute, not the query string. It's a way of *writing* that query string in an HTML attribute value, because in HTML attribute values (**not** query strings), `&` is the beginning of a character entity.

Answer (score 1):

this seems to work:

```
"?foo=myFoo&fooAndBar=myFoo&amp;Bar;bar=myBar".match(/(&\w+;|[^&;])+/g)
> ["?foo=myFoo", "fooAndBar=myFoo&amp;Bar", "bar=myBar"]
```

`&\w+;` to match entities is pretty naive, but you got the idea.